# How to define a generic type in flow that have all the fields optional of specified type

Tags: typescript, flowtype

We can define a generic type in typescript very easily that can have all fields optional with respect to passed generic type. Such type of query are very usefull in type definition to define mongo queries's result as we may not need to get all fields and can validate through optional type specification.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}

const p : Partial<Person> = {
    name:"A"
}
```

How to define same thing using Flow. We are able to use $Keys. but not able to get its type while defining another type as we have done in type script. -- [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; We are not able to get P in Flow. https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number;    
}

type Partial<T> = {
    [$Keys<T>] : 1;  // doubt here how to get type of prop comes in left
}

const p : Partial<Person> = {
    name:"A"
}
```

Actual We are trying to write a type specification for Query. We can't give null or undefined for not specified keys as well.

```
type Department = {
    _id : string,
    name : string,
    type : string
}

type Person = {
    _id : string,
    name : string,
    age : number,
    department : Department
}

type Query <T> = {
    [P in keyOf T ]?: 1 | Query<T[P]> 
}

type Document<T> = {
    [P in keyOf T ]?: T[P] | Document<T[P]>     
}

const personDepartments  : Query<Person> = {
    name:1, department :{name:1}
}
```

This query will return some result as follow

```
{_id:"1",name:"abc",department:{name:"xyz"}}
```

which can be of Document Type

```
const a : Document<Person> = {_id:"1",name:"abc",department:{name:"xyz"}}
```

So we can write a function as following

```
function getResult<T>(query:Query<T>) : Document<t> {
    // code here to query and get result
}
```

It is very straightforward in TypeScript. So I guess there should be way around as well in Flow.

Comment: Hello Team : Is it possible ?

Comment: TL;DR - No answer. But just of curiosity, what's the point of a type where all fields are optional? You'd need to null-check all of them before using it anyway. The only restriction here is for adding fields which aren't in the `Person` type, but is it what you need in the first place? Our way is that we always assume DB returns `mixed`, because the app. has no control over DB, so we never 100% sure what might come from DB. After we get a `mixed`-type result we apply a mapper which makes sure the arrived data is of exact expected type. If it is not an "unexpected data" handler is fired.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. We have actually a use case when we define mongo query and show result on view. We have to show less column on view (ui side) . So we need to make a type definition that can expect less columns. and we can;t make each column optional in main type as while saving a document it is necesary to have value of mandatory columns. But I  believe that it should not possible in flow as it is originated from type script and much of its syntax is similar to typescript. so there should be a way in flow that we are not finding may be due to not documented.

Comment: "So we need to make a type definition that can expect less columns" - so, you're trying to create another type (i.e. PersonForView) where all fields are optional, right? If yes, then my question still stands - why do you need a type where all fields are optional? The view still have to null-check all  fields. Do you need such type at all? "it is originated from type script" - I don't have proofs at the moment, but I doubt Flow originated from TS - they're pretty different, they use completely different type inference algorithms and written in different languages (OCaml and TS respectively).

Comment: In general I don't think it is possible to do exactly the same thing in Flow as you do in TS, at least I don't know a way. What would you say about creating a type for the view (i.e. `type PersonView = { a: string, b: string }`) and a type for Mongo which includes all fields needed for view which extends the type for view (i.e. `type PersonMongoEntity = PersonView & { c: string, d: string }`). In this case you (and compiler) "know" which fields are needed and don't have to null-check anything.

Comment: Thanks Viktor for clarity. To define a type for view seems to be duplicate effort and error prone as there is no way to validate it from being main type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [$Shape](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape) utility:

> Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional

```
type Foo = {
  A: string,
  B: number,
  C: string
};

const t: $Shape<Foo> = {
  A: 'a'
};
```

Another approach would be "spreading" the type (sorry can't find any documentation on it besides [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/5a9fc8f50cc47262593a1654f3dcc503c01b4a40/Changelog.md#v0420)):

```
type Foo = {
  A: string,
  B: number,
  C: string
};

type Partial<T> = { ...T };

const t: Partial<Foo> = {
  A: 'a'
};
```

Now it is truly partial and you **can** skip the keys.

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. We will try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get close with [`$ObjMap<T, F>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap) which applies function type `F` to every property of `T`.

```
type Foo = {
  A: string,
  B: number,
  C: string
};

function makeOptional<T>(t: T): ?T {
  return t;
}

type PartialFoo = $ObjMap<Foo, typeof makeOptional>;

const t: PartialFoo = {
  A: 'a',
  B: null,
  C: undefined
};
```

In this case, however, you still can't skip keys, but can add `null` or `undefined` to their values.

Comment: Thanks EyasSH.

Actual We are trying to write a type specification for Query. We can't give null or undefined for not specified keys as well. As I have edited my question to explain what we want. It is possible in TypeScript straight forward